# why wont my items appear?

Tags: objects

I recently got blender (as i have nothing to do right now) and my cube wont show up when I start the program. It just shows a yellow dot that is in the middle of the item. This problem happens with every mesh I add in. Image below[image]

The yellow outline of the cube only appears when i select the cube mesh. If i don't select it it just shows the yellow dot that you can see in the center of the screen.

If anyone has any idea on why this is happening and how I can fix it then please let me know.

Comment: This could be the result of an incompatible GPU, or out of date graphics drivers. Check here to make sure your GPU is supported - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

Comment: Thank you for the help but using the link attached I cant find out whether my Radeon hd 7520g Processor is compatible with blender. If you know that it isnt then can you let me know Christopher. Thanks

Comment: It isn't fulfilling the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). GCN first generation or later is required while your GPU has the TeraScale 3 micro-architecture.